# Подскажите как в админке добавить кнопку к каждому товару?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-admin

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите как добавить кнопку в админке?
Возможно сделать это сразу через модель?

admin.py

```
        from django.contrib import admin
    from .models import Product,Task


    admin.site.register(Task)

    admin.site.site_header = "My admin panel"

    class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        list_display = ("title","price","rating_reviews","in_stock","amount")

    admin.site.register(Product,ProductAdmin)
```

model.py

```
      class Product(models.Model):
        id_product = models.CharField(max_length=30, db_index=True)
        title = models.CharField(max_length=350, unique=True, db_index=True)
        price = models.CharField(max_length=30, db_index=True)
        url = models.CharField(max_length=350, unique=True, db_index=True)
        description = models.TextField(max_length=5000,db_index=True)
        category = models.CharField(max_length=100, db_index=True)
        rating_reviews = models.CharField(default="without rating",max_length=100, db_index=True)
        in_stock = models.BooleanField(default=True)
        brand = models.CharField(default="without brand",max_length=100, db_index=True)
        amount = models.CharField(default="quantity not indicated",max_length=10, db_index=True)
        delivery_price = models.CharField(default="Free delivery",max_length=30, db_index=True)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.title
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ну если просто кнопку которая ничего не делает

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Product,Task
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe


admin.site.register(Task)

admin.site.site_header = "My admin panel"

class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ("title","price","rating_reviews","in_stock","amount","button")

    def button(self, obj):
        return mark_safe(f'<a class="button" >Кнопка</a>')


admin.site.register(Product,ProductAdmin)
```

Comment: Спасибо,помогло.Но да, действие должно при нажатии выполняться,при нажатии переходить по урлу который в моделе Produck,можете ещё это подсказать?

Comment: @Alexey return mark_safe(f'<a class="button" href={obj.url} >Кнопка</a>') если я вас правильно понял. в url ссылка?

Comment: Спасибо помогло)

Comment: @Alexey пожалуйста)